# Using value object as as identifier with RavenDB .NET client

Tags: .net, ravendb

I'm looking for an example of how to use a custom class as an identifier with RavenDB .NET client. I have something like this:

```csharp
class Product
{
    public ProductId Id { get; }

    public Product()
    {
        Id = new ProductId(Guid.NewGuid());
    }
    // ...
}
```

where ProductId looks like this:

```csharp
class ProductId
{
    public Guid Value { get; }
    
    public ProductId(Guid value)
    {
        // validation
        Value = value
    }
}
```

I haven't found any information on that topic in the documentation. Does anyone know to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A document identifier (document ID) is always a **string** that is associated with the document.
See: https://ravendb.net/docs/article-page/5.0/csharp/server/kb/document-identifier-generation

**You can have the server generate the Guid for you:**.
See: https://ravendb.net/docs/article-page/5.0/csharp/server/kb/document-identifier-generation#guid 
To do that you assign: `Id = string.Empty`
See: https://ravendb.net/docs/article-page/5.0/csharp/client-api/document-identifiers/working-with-document-identifiers#autogenerated-ids

**Else, maybe:**

1. Refactor the current Id property to:
   `public ProductId MyId { get; }`
   and init with
   `MyId = new ProductId(Guid.NewGuid());`
2. Add another property on the `Product` class 
   `public string Id { get; set; }`
3. Use [OnBeforeStore](https://ravendb.net/docs/article-page/5.0/Csharp/client-api/session/how-to/subscribe-to-events#onbeforestore) to assign:
   `Id = MyId.Value`